# Transactional replication initialize from database snapshot spare file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to know, is it possible to initialize transactional replication from database snapshot spare file for existing replication which is inactive and expired default more than 72 hours.

I have a SQL 2014 which is replicating to SQL 2019 & 2014 as well. it is big database and table.
I cannot do initialize from backup since the existing subscriber having other objects as well.

Can anyone have steps or scripts to initialize transactional replication from database snapshot. That would be helpful.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks JD for the update.